# BeautifulSoup get links between strings

Tags: python, string, beautifulsoup, hyperlink, between

So I am using BS4 to get the following out of a Website:

```
<div>Some TEXT with <a href="some Link">some LINK</a>
and some continuing TEXT with following <a href="some Link">some LINK</a> inside.</div>
```

What I need to get is:

```
"Some TEXT with some LINK ("https// - actual Link") and some continuing TEXT with following some LINK ("https//- next Link") inside."
```

I am struggeling with this for some time now and don't know how to get there ... tried before, after, between, [:], all sort of in-Array-passing methods to get everything together.

I hope someone can help me with this because I am am new to Python. Thanks in advance.

Comment: how about searching all `<a>` inside `<div>` - i.e. `find('div').find_all('a')`. After that you should have list with all `<a>` and you can `get_text()` or `["href"]` from every element on list.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `str.join` with an iteration over `soup.contents`:

```
import bs4
html = '''<div>Some TEXT with <a href="https// - actual Link">some LINK</a> and some continuing TEXT with following <a href="https//- next Link">some LINK</a> inside.</div>'''
result = ''.join(i if isinstance(i, bs4.element.NavigableString) else f'{i.text} ({i["href"]})' for i in bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser').div.contents)
```

Output:

```
'Some TEXT with some LINK (https// - actual Link) and some continuing TEXT with following some LINK (https//- next Link) inside.'
```

---

Edit: ignoring `br` tags:

```
html = '''<div>Some TEXT <br> with <a href="https// - actual Link">some LINK</a> and some continuing TEXT with <br> following <a href="https//- next Link">some LINK</a> inside.</div>'''
result = ''.join(i if isinstance(i, bs4.element.NavigableString) else f'{i.text} ({i["href"]})' for i in bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser').div.contents \
    if getattr(i, 'name', None) != 'br')
```

Edit 2: recursive solution:

```
def form_text(s):
  if isinstance(s, (str, bs4.element.NavigableString)):
    yield s
  elif s.name == 'a':
     yield f'{s.get_text(strip=True)} ({s["href"]})'
  else:
     for i in getattr(s, 'contents', []):
        yield from form_text(i)

html = '''<div>Some TEXT <i>other text in </i> <br> with <a href="https// - actual Link">some LINK</a> and some continuing TEXT with <br> following <a href="https//- next Link">some LINK</a> inside.</div>'''
print(' '.join(form_text(bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser'))))
```

Output:

```
Some TEXT  other text in     with  some LINK (https// - actual Link)  and some continuing TEXT with   following  some LINK (https//- next Link)  inside.
```

Also, whitespace may become an issue due to the presence of `br` tags, etc. To work around this, you can use `re.sub`:

```
import re
result = re.sub('\s+', ' ', ' '.join(form_text(bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser'))))
```

Output:

```
'Some TEXT other text in with some LINK (https// - actual Link) and some continuing TEXT with following some LINK (https//- next Link) inside.'
```

Comment: I am trying to implement your code, because I think it will work. BUT I get the same error all the time: result = ''.join(i if isinstance(i, bs4.element.NavigableString), line 232, in <genexpr> else f'{i.text} ({i["href"]})', line 992, in __getitem__ return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 'href'

Comment: @dustixx That is because there are probably tags other than `a` in the example you are running. This code above is designed to run on samples only containing strings or `a` tags. Either way, please post the sample you are currently using and I will edit my post.

Comment: Yes I think the <br/> tags, which sometimes occure, are the problem ...

Comment: is there a way to ignore the <br/> tags from the html container? @Ajax1234

Comment: It is still not working for me, sorry. I am trying to adapt your code so it will work for me, but as I don't understand it properly, I cannot.
For example: as my html variable is already html =
soup.find(id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl0" -> can't I just adapt your code like this: result = ''.join(i if isinstance(i, bs4.element.NavigableString) else f'{i.text} ({i["href"]})' for i in html if getattr(i, 'name', None) != 'br') ->?
With your changes, the links will not be in the result and I don't understand why ...

Comment: Just found out that some phrases have a <i> tag, which I need. Is there any way to adapt your code, that I can define what to pass and what to ignore? because I tryied for example:
result = ''.join(i if isinstance(i, bs4.element.NavigableString) else f'{i.text} ({i["href"]})' for i in
                         text_container if getattr(i, 'name', None) != 'i' or getattr(i, 'name', None) != 'br') -> to ignore the <i> tags, but it is not working .... like this I get the exception for the <br> tags.

Comment: @dustixx I think a generic recursive approach is best in this instance. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: You are truly a genius! Thank you very much for helping me and for the patience. I will mark you as the author of this part of code in my script. Thanks, again and have a nice day.

Comment: @dustixx No problem, glad to help!

Comment: I just found out that the name of the Link gets "printed" out twice. One time before the (LINK) and one time after. Also, sometimes it "prints" out three blanks after each other ... you can see it in your Output too. I got rid of the blanks by simply .replace('   ', ' ') but don't know what to do about the double link name. I am so sorry for bothering you that much XD

Comment: @dustixx No problem at all, my mistake, the solution was iterating over the contents of links that had already been accounted for in `f'{s.get_text(strip=True)} ({s["href"]})'`. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: One last question, I promise. When my html variable contains a <br> tag, the function will remove/ignore it in the result. But as I use the program to compare two strings, I need the result variable to be exactly like it's showing on the website (with all its line-breaks(\n) included) I realized that you used this part in your code: x != '\n'. I think it has to do something with the linebreak, but I cannot fix it to my needs. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: @dustixx No problem at all! I updated the recursive function under "Edit2" to reflect this.